# I changed Mainboard in S6 its wrong country code and does not work now what?

Tags: factory-reset, hardware

As above the board was locked to AT&T but i got the code for that I put my open sim card in it , it picks up wifi and looks like network signal but when i try to phone with it is says dialing ...dialing and hangs up. any help would be great !

Comment: download ROM according to your region and flash with Odin